# Tables Relationships in magento2

Tags: magento2

Can anyone tell me **one-to-one** , **one-to-many** and **many-to-many**  Relationship in magento2 tables.
Which tables has **one-to-one** Relationships ? Which tables has one-to-many with which tables ? i just neend 1 or 2 table examples not need too detail
I want to learn this am beginner in **Magento**.

Thanks in Advances

Answer (score 1):

An example for **one-to-one** relations are the sales tables and their corresponding grid tables, for example
`sales_order` and `sales_order_grid`

For **one-to-many** you may look at EAV entity tables and their attribute tables, for example `catalog_product_entity` and `catalog_product_entity_varchar`,`catalog_product_entity_int` etc. 
Another example for this is `sales_order` and `sales_order_item`.

For **many-to-many** you can look at the realation table products to category, `catalog_category_product` which maps entries from `catalog_category_entity` and `catalog_product_entity`.